# NSTextField - White text on black background, but black cursor

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, customization, nstextfield

I've setup an `NSTextField` with text color as white, and the background color as (black despite not rendering the background color, so its transparent). All in Interface Builder.

The problem I am having is **the cursor is black, and hardly visible**. **Does the cursor not represent the text color?** Any ideas how I can fix this?

Otherwise, the `NSTextField` looks like it cannot be edited.

Comment: please mark uliwitness's answer as the correct one

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to use NSTextView and `- (void)setInsertionPointColor:(NSColor *)color`.

Comment: No. The best bet is to subclass NSTextField, as described by uliwitness, below.

Answer (score 38):

Since in practice the NSText* returned by -currentEditor for an NSTextField is always an NSTextView*, I added the following code to my custom NSTextField subclass:

```
-(BOOL) becomeFirstResponder
{
    BOOL    success = [super becomeFirstResponder];
    if( success )
    {
        // Strictly spoken, NSText (which currentEditor returns) doesn't
        // implement setInsertionPointColor:, but it's an NSTextView in practice.
        // But let's be paranoid, better show an invisible black-on-black cursor
        // than crash.
        NSTextView* textField = (NSTextView*) [self currentEditor];
        if( [textField respondsToSelector: @selector(setInsertionPointColor:)] )
            [textField setInsertionPointColor: [NSColor whiteColor]];
    }
    return success;
}
```

So if you're already replacing this class because you're doing custom background drawing, this might be a more encapsulated solution. Maybe there's even a way to move this up into NSCell, which would be cleaner since NSCell is the one doing the drawing and knowing the colors anyway.

Comment: This should really be marked as the correct answer; using the `textDidBegin/end:` delegate methods as proposed in other answers does not change the caret color until the user starts typing. This one changes it immediately on focus.

Comment: You may want to add a corresponding `-(BOOL) resignFirstResponder` method that changes the color back to black, since the field editor in question is shared by all textFields in the window. Leaving it set to white is probably not a good idea, as other fields won't automatically set it to black.

Comment: Note that resignFirstResponder will not work in this case because it will be called right after becomeFirstResponder when the field editor becomes first responder.

Answer (score 28):

## TextField Insertion Point Color

```
NSTextField *textField = self.textField;
NSColor *insertionPointColor = [NSColor blueColor];

NSTextView *fieldEditor = (NSTextView*)[textField.window fieldEditor:YES
                                                           forObject:textField];
fieldEditor.insertionPointColor = insertionPointColor;
```

Comment: just make sure you call it in viewDidAppear cause fieldEditor will be still nil in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear

Answer (score 14):

Assuming that you are wanting to set the color of the insertion caret and not the mouse cursor then the suggestion of using `setInsertionPointColor:` should work.

However, you do not necessarily need to change from using `NSTextField` to `NSTextView`. The field editor for window that the `NSTextField` is in is an `NSTextView`. So when your `NSTextField` becomes the key view you could grab the field editor and call `setInsertionPointColor:` on that. You may need to reset the color when your field stops being the key view.

You can get the field editor by using `NSWindow`'s `fieldEditor:forObject:` or `NSCell`'s `fieldEditorForView:`.

If you have a subclass of NSTextField you can have it use a custom subclass of NSTextFieldCell and override `-(NSText*)setUpFieldEditorAttributes:(NSText*)textObj`. In that method you can set the insertion point color once and it will stay while the field editor is active for this text field. Though when the field editor is moved to another edit field the insertion point color will remain unless you reset it.

Comment: This is a fantastic way to change the insertion point color on an NSSecureTextField. Thanks!

Comment: But `fieldEditor:forObject:` returns an `NSText` object. I cannot call `setInsertionPointColor:` on an `NSText`.

Comment: I no longer have access to my original code but NSTextView is a subclass of NSText and if you look at the interface for NSTextView it has a isFieldEditor method. You might try using isKindOfClass: to test if the NSText is really a NSTextView. Another thing would be to try to use NSCell's fieldEditorForView: like in JJD's answer.

Comment: This is not correct. `textDidBeginEditing:` and `textDidEndEditing:` do NOT inform you of changes in the NSTextField's key state. Those methods will only fire once the user starts typing text into the field. If you simply click on the field to make it key, those methods do NOT fire and you will therefore see a black caret until you type the first character.

Answer (score 5):

I've called `insertionPointColor` in `viewDidLoad` and app crashes.

I fixed this by calling `insertionPointColor` on `viewDidAppear`.

For **Swift** developers:

Set insertionPointColor method into extension:

```
extension NSTextField {
    public func customizeCursorColor(_ cursorColor: NSColor) {
        let fieldEditor = self.window?.fieldEditor(true, for: self) as! NSTextView
        fieldEditor.insertionPointColor = cursorColor
    }
}
```

and call

```
 override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()
        textField.customizeCursorColor(NSColor.red)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4 Solution**

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    guard let window = _textField.window, let fieldEditor = window.fieldEditor(true, for: _textField) as? NSTextView else { return }
    fieldEditor.insertionPointColor = .white
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the great answer of [Jon Steinmetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3493/jon-steinmetz) I created the following example.

I added a `NSSecureTextField` to the application view and connected it to the `IBOutlet` of the member variable I placed into `AppDelegate`.

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize password = m_password;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    assert(m_password);
    self.password.backgroundColor = [NSColor blackColor];
}
```

Then I created a custom `NSSecureTextField` class. I noticed that is in some cases not enough to set the colors in `awakeFromNib` but I cannot give a reason for this.

```
@implementation CustomSecureTextField

- (void)customize {
    // Customize the text and caret color.
    NSColor* foregroundColor = [NSColor whiteColor];
    self.textColor = foregroundColor;
    [[self.cell fieldEditorForView:self] setInsertionPointColor:foregroundColor];   
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self customize];
}

- (void)textDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification*)notification {
    // Called when the user inputs a character.
    [self customize];
}

- (void)textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification*)notification {
    // Called when the user clicks into the field for the first time.
    [self customize];   
}

- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification {
    // Just in case ... for the paranoid programmer!
    [self customize];
}


@end
```

**Note:** Though, I do not understand why the background color cannot be set when I do this in the derived class like with the `textColor`. That would allow to get rid of the `IBOutlet` and the member variable.

Comment: it's probably worth calling `super`'s implementation of the functions you are overriding.

Answer (score 1):

easiest way is

```
 override func viewDidAppear() {
    if let fieldEditor = self.view.window?.fieldEditor(true, for: self) as? NSTextView{
        fieldEditor.insertionPointColor = NSColor.black
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this code in swift

```
 if let editor = textField.currentEditor() as? NSTextView{
     editor.insertionPointColor = myColor ?? .black
 }
```

Comment: Please, check the dates before posting new answers. This question is almost 12 years old.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Objective-C runtime selector capture combined with [uliwitness's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9111968/4149826), you can achieve it without subclassing NSTextField, here I use RxCocoa's `methodInvoked` as an example:

```swift
import Cocoa
import RxCocoa

extension NSTextField {
    func withCursorColor(_ color: NSColor) {
        rx.methodInvoked(#selector(becomeFirstResponder))
            .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] _ in
                guard let editor = self.currentEditor() as? NSTextView else { return }
                editor.insertionPointColor = color
            })
            .disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
    }
}
```