# NSSecureTextField hide cursor

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite, nstextfield

I am trying to hide blinking cursor of NSSecureTextField. I have tried

```
[[passwordField.cell fieldEditorForView:passwordField] setInsertionPointColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
```

but it is not working.

I have also tried many answers on the question 
[NSTextField - White text on black background, but black cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258300/nstextfield-white-text-on-black-background-but-black-cursor) but not able to completely hide it.

Answer (score 1):

This is in Swift, but it worked for me:

```
    if let cell = secureTextField.cell() as? NSTextFieldCell {
        if let editor = cell.fieldEditorForView(secureTextField) {
            editor.insertionPointColor = NSColor.whiteColor()
        }
    }
```

Oh I see the only difference is that I use `NSColor.whiteColor()` instead of `clearColor()`.

Comment: white color is working also for me, but i need to hide the cursor with clear color as i have coloured background.